# Styling of Grid so that each cell is a square

Tags: style, grid-layouts

How to make each cell of `Grid` being a square?

```
Style[Grid[Partition[ToUpperCase[Alphabet[][[1 ;; 25]]], 5], 
  Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 40]
```

[image]

Comment: ```ItemSize->{1,1}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jus for curiosity (I was not aware of `ItemSize->{1,1}` suggested by @Jean-Pierre) -
a brute force method :-D.

It depends on increment of `i`, how precise you want to be. I chose `0.1` so probably not exact squares.

```
Clear[i]
grid=Style[Grid[Partition[ToUpperCase[Alphabet[][[1;;25]]],5],Frame->All,Alignment->{Center,Center},Spacings->{i,Automatic}],40];
i=0;
While[#[[1]]/#[[2]]&@ImageDimensions[Rasterize[grid]]<1,i=i+0.1]
i
grid
Clear[grid,i]
```

[image]